# What is the right Charsets to read rfc1006 protocoll response

Tags: java, character-encoding

I try to make a TCP/IP connection to a Siemens S7300 CPU using RFC1006 protocoll. So far so good I am still fighting with the connection itself. i did not find so much about this protocol. The issue at the monent is that I cannot identify the connection response from the PLC. I know that there is the TSAP, which is "TCP-1", included but many other chars i cannot read as there are some empty fields and 
Does anybody know which charset I have to use to read the PLC response!? I played with some of the standard Charset but they are useless. Even worse if I use the UTF-16 charset while creating my byte array the output is different than using the StandardCharset.UTF_16 while I thought they should be the same.

```
public void startPort1(int port) throws IOException{
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println(clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
    out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    while(true) {
        if (clientSocket.getInputStream().available() >0) {
            System.out.println();
            char[] plcSend = new char[clientSocket.getInputStream().available()];
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            if (in.ready()) {
                in.read(plcSend, 0, clientSocket.getInputStream().available() - 1);
                
                byte[] plcSendBytes = new String(plcSend).getBytes("UTF-16");
                String response = new String(plcSendBytes);                 
                System.out.println("UTF-16 ===> "); 
                System.out.println(response);
                System.out.println();
                byte[] plcSendBytes1 = new String(plcSend).getBytes();
                String response1 = new String(plcSendBytes1, StandardCharsets.UTF_16);                  
                System.out.println("StandardCharsets.UTF_16 ===> ");
                System.out.println(response1);
            }else {
                System.out.println("different story");
            }
```

and this is the weird output
[I am not able to copy he output String so i need an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjyGI.png)

Comment: You'd probably get more help if you print out the data you are receiving as hex bytes

Comment: thanks tgdavies i was stupid enough to not thought about it or even thought that byte would give me HEX. However one more question comes with that: What is the difference between byte and char than? They give the same result so when and why to use what?

Comment: In Java a `char` is an unsigned 16 bit number, while a `byte` is a signed 8 bit number.